# Requisição ajax com append antes de abrir modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap

Por algum motivo não estou conseguindo fazer este append funcionar.

```
function mostrarUploads(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/painel/mostrarUploads",
      async: false,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {_token: jQuery(".token").val(), id: id},
      success: function(e) {
        e.forEach(function(item, indice) {
          $('#bodyTabelaUploads tbody').append('<tr><td>TESTE</td></tr>');
        });
      }
    });
}
```

Tenho essa tabela:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="tabelaUploads">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nome do arquivo</th>
                                <th>Ações</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody id = "bodyTabelaUploads">

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Estou chamando o método antes de abrir um modal. Ele é um método assíncrono, mas estou usando async: false.

Será que por este método ser assíncrono, o modal abre antes, e eu não vejo a linha sendo adicionada? OBS: console.log(e) retorna resultados!!

Comment: Somente pra complementar: Ajax síncrono está deprecado desde o ```jQuery``` 1.8, então recomendo que procure fazer tudo de forma assíncrona

Comment: Ok, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primeiro, `async: false` é sempre uma má ideia. O `$.ajax` retorna uma `promise`, então, abra o seu modal na continuação do mesmo.

```
function mostrarUploads(id) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/painel/mostrarUploads",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {_token: jQuery(".token").val(), id: id},
    success: function(e) {
      e.forEach(function(item, indice) {
        $('#bodyTabelaUploads tbody').append('<tr><td>TESTE</td></tr>');
      });
    }
  });
}

mostrarUploads(id).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  //exibir modal.
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  //exibir mensagem de erro.
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu comentário.

Quando utilizo desta maneira que você disse, o browser retorna "cannot read property done of undefined" como se a função não existisse. Ela está declarada em cima do uso do método.

Alguma ideia do que possa ser? Vou tentar utilizar o $.when() que li a respeito também.

Comment: Olha, a sua resposta me deu uma boa inspiração que funcionou. Usei o .done na própria requisição ajax. O único problema que eu vejo nesta aproximação é que pode demorar bastante pra carregar isso e a experiência de usuário ficar ruim. Porém, não deixa de ser uma solução. Alguém conhece alguma maneira melhor de se fazer isso?

Comment: @mas se fizer um `async: false` não fará que o retorno seja mais rápido, a diferença é que a pagina irá deixar de responder enquanto espera pelo retorno.

Answer (score 1):

O problema no seu código, é que sua tabela se chama `tabelaUploads`, e você está procurando por um `tbody` no corpo dessa tabela aqui: `$('#bodyTabelaUploads tbody')`, o que não irá retornar nada.

Troque `$('#bodyTabelaUploads tbody')` por `$('#tabelaUploads tbody')`

**PORÉM**

Gostaria de ressaltar que requisições AJAX síncronas já estão deprecadas e devem ser evitadas, pois eventualmente provavelmente serão totalmente removidas (daqui a muitos, muitos anos).

O próprio jQuery já nos avisa disso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Realmente não havia visto este detalhe do tbody, obrigado!

Porém, ainda preciso de ajuda na questão do sincronismo. Me parece que preciso terminar esta requisição antes de abrir o modal. Ou será possível abrir o modal e mesmo assim depois dele aberto eu modificar a tabela 'dinamicamente' com o append?

Comment: Você pode fazer de diversas maneiras. Pode abrir a modal e mostrar algo como ```carregando...``` enquanto faz a requisição. Ou então pode mostrar a modal somente quando a requisição terminar

Comment: Sim, obrigado pela resposta! Acredito que não exista algo que fuja disso.

Comment: Você não tem como escapar de uma eventual demora do servidor. Você só tem que avisar o usuário de que está esperando, e travando a tela com uma requisição síncrona não é a melhor maneira :)